# Show Windows Search Box on all screens

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a 3 screen extended display running on Windows 10 Pro with the latest patches as at the time of writing.  I have disabled Cortana but have the search box shown next to the Start menu button on my main display.

I would like to have the search box appear on both of the other screens as well.  How would I do this?

Comment: Do you have the the task bar showing on the other displays? I have a standard install with the taskbar showing on each display and I have the search box on my secondary monitor - BUT, it's shown as a magnifying glass symbol, not the full search box.  But when clicked on the behavior is the same.

Comment: Well spotted mark.  Yes, I do have the task-bar showing and the setup is indeed the same as yours.  I probably didn't notice it earlier, but I could have sworn the magnifying glass wasn't there.  You should add that as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a multi display desktop with Cortana disabled (Desktop mode, taskbar showing on all displays, taskbar on the bottom of the screen), the primary display has the "Search Windows" search box, and any additional displays have the magnifying glass or search icon as pictured below.

[image]

You can change the primary screen to this symbol by right clicking the taskbar -> Search -> Show search icon - as per below (if you want to save some real-estate)

[image]

I think with Cortana enabled that is replaced with the Cortana symbol.

### Update 10 May 2018

With each version of Windows 10 Cortana has become more difficult to disable. The 'Search' option when you right-click on the main toolbar has been replaced with 'Cortana' - the same options apply.  It also looks like the default behaviour is to include Cortana on all taskbars.

Comment: This appears to be out of date? There is now a taskbar settings option and inside I can't find anything about a search icon or box.