# Where are the Windows Search options in the context menu?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, search

I am running Windows 10 and I can't seem to access options to change the appearance of the search on the taskbar. Looking at this post [Show Windows Search Box on all screens](https://superuser.com/questions/1077661/show-windows-search-box-on-all-screens) I should be able to right click the task bar and choose "Show search icon" from "Search." This isn't an option for me. See screenshot below. Right now I have a bar on my main screen and icons on my other monitors. I would like all of them to be icons because the bar takes up a lot of real estate. If anything, I'm okay with removing it entirely. This "Type here to search" bar is just annoying. This user ([Search box icon keeps disapearing](https://superuser.com/questions/1317646/search-box-icon-keeps-disapearing/1317654#1317654)) has the opposite problem, but it's showing to make changes in the Local Group Policy Editor or Registry Editor. See additional screenshots that show I'm missing these options.

- [Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMhEp.png)
- [Local Group Policy Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rQjs.png)
- [Registry Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUehE.png)

Comment: Maybe turn off News and Interests so that the left hand box collapses.  That makes it easier to use the search icon. Search is not in the right context menu.

Comment: News and Interests also isn't showing up.

Comment: I am nor sure then what is causing the issue. Your desktop is very difficult to see, but it seems to be very busy.

Comment: I have 4 applications open, all of which are minimized. There are a handful of text files on the desktop that need to be cleaned up. I don't know how this would affect what appears on this menu.